# how to access package in public folder from node_modules folder in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mean-stack, node-modules

i have `MEAN stack` application.
In public folder i have `AngularJs` application.

**Structure**

[image]

Here in `index.html` i am trying to access a package, which is present in `node_modules`.

**Can any please tell me how to access this?**

Comment: `../node_modules/path/to/the/package`? You will need to allow the `node_modules` directory from your routes though.

Comment: is there any other way to access it ?@31piy

Comment: Can't really figure out without knowing more about your app's code. Most probably, you may want to bundle your front end code with webpack or similar tool, which will bundle all the required node modules in a JS file.

Comment: i am not using webpack or any tools @31piy

Answer (score 1):

As @31Py said, you can reference using `../node_modules/path/to/the/package`

**OR**

It's always better to create separate dependencies in `package.json` file for public folder(front end code).
This helps you to organize both the code separate, while bundling front end, running task runners(grunt, gulp) and you would know which packages are for front end.
In index.html referencing the node modules will be `/node_modules/path/to/the/package`

Some reference Links with comments in the section.

1. [Separating Frontend & Backend Dependencies with Gulp/Yarn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50687251/separating-frontend-backend-dependencies-with-gulp-yarn)
2. [Separating package.json for frontend and backend with shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41294491/separating-package-json-for-frontend-and-backend-with-shared-code)

Comment: i don't want to separate backend and frontend. is there any other way other then @31Py suggestion ?